# VueJS: How to pass instance data to an instance method called via anonymous event handler?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

To test whether Vue event binding has access to instance state/data, I pass `msg` (instance data) in an anonymous fn which calls `alertMsg(msg)` (instance method). but it seems only the default event obj (in this case Mouse event) gets passed to `alertMsg(msg)` and not `msg`.

Even tried `(ev, msg)` i.e. passing `ev` (event obj) and `msg` as second arg but still only the event obj is passed

**Template**

```
<div id="app">
  <p>{{ msg }}</p>
  <div @click="msg => { alertMsg(msg)}">test</div>
</div>
```

**Vue Instance**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Hello World'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    alertMsg(e, msg) {
      console.log(e)
      alert(msg)
    }
  }
})
```

How to make this work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the special $event variable, as per documentation:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers

Such as:

```html
    <div id="app">
      <p>{{ msg }}</p>
      <div @click="alertMsg($event, msg)">test</div>
    </div>
```

In case you want to access "msg" directly from within the function, use "this.msg".